# Is there a splat operator in Starlark / Bazel?

Tags: bazel

Is there a splat operator in Bazel? Like pythons `*`, or Javacripts `...`?

I'm interested in the case where I need to unpack a list into another. What I would like to achieve is something like this:

```
some_rule (
    name = "target_name",
    src = [
        "file1.txt",
        "file2.txt",
        *get_more_files()
    ]
)
```

In this example `get_more_files` would return a list of file names, which would be unpacked into `src` and sit alongside `file1.txt` and `file2.txt`.

*Note*: I am aware of the `extend` method.

Comment: `srcs = [ .. ] + get_more_files()`?

Comment: Not as elegant as a splat, but good enough nonetheless. (Feel kind of stupid for not thinking about it myself)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
srcs = [ .. ] + get_more_files()
```

should do the job